# i am trying to add a foreign key to existing table in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE PROGRAM_MODULE_REGISTRATION (
PR_ID NUMBER(2) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
P_ID NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
MO_ID  NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
```

This is the table I created.

```
ALTER TABLE PROGRAM_MODULE__REGISTRATION 
ADD FOREIGN KEY(P_ID),
REFERENCES PROGRAM;
```

I am trying to add foreign keys to existing columns. This is for P_ID which is from program table.
And Mo_id from module table.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I get an error message saying "missing keyword"

Answer (score 0):

```
ADD FOREIGN KEY(P_ID),
                     ^----spurious comma
REFERENCES PROGRAM;
```

Comment: I tried it but i get a error message "table or view does not exist"

Comment: so d you have a `PROGRAM` table? And note that your alter statement has TWO `__`, v.s. ONE `_` in the `create` query.

Comment: I fixed my problem myself. Anyway thanks for your help.